# SQL Function to extract time from Datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a function to extract a timespan field from a datetime2 field?

e.g

datetime2 has '01/01/2009 12:30:00'

i want '12:30:00'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either just use the CAST function:

```
SELECT CAST(@datetime2var AS TIME)
```

or assign your "datetime2" variable to another variable of type "TIME":

```
DECLARE @timeVal TIME 

SET @timeVal = @datetime2var

SELECT @timeVal
```

Marc

Answer (score -1):

You will need something like

select convert(varchar(10), sysdate, 108)

The complete list of Date Time Functions is here :
[link text](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: I didn't downvote because I'm not sure, but sysdate doesn't work with SQL-Server 2005. I believe it is an oracle command.  Use GetDate().